# Consulta con INNER JOIN en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Cordial saludo.

esta consulta en la base de datos me devuelve los valores correspondientes, pero desde php me muestra los criterios tbl_comunas.comuna, tbl_alumno.comun, en cada linea de color purpura lo cuál no estoy seguro si es un error pero igual en el resultado no me cargan los datos de la grafica que deseo mostrar y no me sale ningun error.

Este es el codigo con la consulta:

```
<?php
    include_once('conexion.php');
    class Procesar extends Model{

        public function __construct(){ 
            parent::__construct(); 
        }

        public function build_report($year){
            $total = array();
            for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){
                //$month = $i+1;
                $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT grado, COUNT(id_alumno) AS cantidad, tbl_comunas.comuna AS comuna
                                         FROM tbl_alumnos LEFT JOIN tbl_comunas
                                         ON tbl_alumnos.comuna = tbl_comunas.comuna
                                         WHERE grado ='$year'
                                         GROUP BY tbl_comunas.comuna"); 
                $total[$i] = $i++;
                foreach ($sql as $key){ 
                    $total[] = ($key['total'] == null)? 0 : $key['total']; }
            }            
            return $total;
        }

    }

    if($_POST['year']){
        $class = new Procesar;
        $run = $class->build_report($_POST['year']);
        exit(json_encode($run));
    }
?>
```

Este es el código del index.php que genera la grafica, en este cargo el aray que me genera la consulta en realidad debe haber una consulta por cada comuna y dependiendo esta colora el valor en cada label de donde dice Comuna 1, Comuna 2.......

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Estadistica</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chartJS/Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
        .caja{
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 250px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
        }
        .caja select{
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .resultados{
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 40px;
            width: 1000px;
        }
    </style>
    <body> 
        <div class="caja">
            <select onChange="mostrarResultados(this.value);">
                <?php
                    for($i=701;$i<1109;$i++){
                        if($i == 701){
                            echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="resultados"><canvas id="grafico"></canvas></div>
    </body>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(mostrarResultados(2015));  
                function mostrarResultados(year){
                    $('.resultados').html('<canvas id="grafico"></canvas>');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'php/procesar.php',
                        data: 'year='+year,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success:function(response){

                            console.log(response);

                            var Datos = {
                                    labels : ['Comuna 1', 'Comuna 2', 'Comuna 3', 'Comuna 4', 'Comuna 5', 'Comuna 6', 'Comuna 7', 'Nulos'],
                                    datasets : [
                                        {
                                            fillColor : 'rgba(91,228,146,0.6)', //COLOR DE LAS BARRAS
                                            strokeColor : 'rgba(57,194,112,0.7)', //COLOR DEL BORDE DE LAS BARRAS
                                            highlightFill : 'rgba(73,206,180,0.6)', //COLOR "HOVER" DE LAS BARRAS
                                            highlightStroke : 'rgba(66,196,157,0.7)', //COLOR "HOVER" DEL BORDE DE LAS BARRAS
                                            data : response
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            var contexto = document.getElementById('grafico').getContext('2d');
                            window.Barra = new Chart(contexto).Bar(Datos, { responsive : true });
                            Barra.clear();
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: De que grafica hablas? si los resultados son correctos, cual es el error que estas teniendo?

Comment: El error es que no me cargan los datos en este archivo para mostrarlos en una grafica,

Comment: La clase esta devolviendo un solo valor.. total es un solo numero.. vos que queres que sea?